# get "event name" using web3

Tags: events, web3.py, python

I want to build a listener in python using web3 as usual.
The issue is that I have a lot of event on my contract (let say 30), and depending the event I have an action to do. Here is my code, and I'll explain just after my issue :

```
def handle_event(event):
    receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(event['transactionHash'])

    # TO IMPROVE
    result_event_temp = contract.events._Event1().processReceipt(receipt)
    if len(result_event_temp) == 1:
        result_event = result_event_temp

    result_event_temp = contract.events._Event2().processReceipt(receipt)
    if len(result_event_temp) == 1:
        result_event = result_event_temp
    #END TO IMPROVE

    my_event = result_event[0]['event']
    if (my_event == '_Event1':
        dosomething
    elif (my_event == '_Event2':
        dosomethingelse


def main():
    block_filter = w3.eth.filter({'fromBlock': 'latest', 'address': address})
    log_loop(block_filter, 2)


def log_loop(event_filter, poll_interval):
    while True:
        for event in event_filter.get_new_entries():
            handle_event(event)
            time.sleep(poll_interval)
```

maybe you understand my issue : I cannot know the name of the event (variable my_event) before getting the result for all my possible event. Here I put example for 2, but if I have 10, or 100, it can be a nightmare to test them one by one with  contract.events._EventXX().processReceipt(receipt)

Is there any possibilities to get the name of the event directly in one shot or not?
something like :

```
my_event = event['eventName']
```

with that I will be able to delete all the box between "# TO IMPROVE" in my code

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution?